# How to change firefox proxy from webdriver?

Tags: python, firefox, proxy, webdriver

how can I access Firefox proxy settings from Python Webdriver and change them to make Firefox use modified proxy settings *without needing to restart it*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible from the outside of Firefox. Have a look at [FoxyProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/2464). It allows you to define a proxy per URL pattern.